# BLE ScanFilter for device address does not work on Android 9 (Google Pixel XL)

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-pixel

We are filtering our BLE scan on a number of MAC addresses by

```
List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
for(String addr : mBleAddrs) {

                if(BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(addr)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "VALID addr: " + addr);
                    ScanFilter deviceFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                            .setDeviceAddress(addr)
                            .build();
                    filters.add(deviceFilter);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "INVALID addr: " + addr);
                }
}
mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settingsBuilder.build(), mScanCallback);
```

When running this on Android 7 and 8 devices it all works fine but when running it on a Google Pixel XL with Android Version 9 it does not yield any results at all. If I remove the filtering I get results on that phone. Anyone knows how to solve this or does some phones simply not support certain types of filtering?

**EDIT** To be clear, we are scanning in the foreground with the screen turned on!

Comment: https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue/wiki/Android-BLE-Issues have a look for a comprehensive list of issues

Comment: Rather the opposite, that thread describes how `setDeviceAddress` for filtering is working instead of scanning for UUID's, whereas I am having issues with using filtering of device address. And its also 4 years old describing ancient things whereas I only have issues with our newest OS and phone (all other devices work with the code).

Comment: And the comprehensive list does not mention either the Google Pixel XL device or the newest Android 9. Apart from that I must say its an informative link!

Comment: Did you find the root cause?

Comment: No, we're still avoiding filtering for ble address on all our devices :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to a randomized address as mentioned at https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/:

> Warning: a device implementing Bluetooth 4.2’s LE Privacy feature will randomize its public MAC address periodically, so a MAC address obtained via scanning should not generally be used as a long-term means to identify a device — unless the firmware guarantees that it’s not rotating MAC addresses or if it has an out-of-band way to communicate what it’s current public MAC address is.